# How to use regex in python to search for repeated "+" sign and avoid multiple repeat error

Tags: python, regex

When searching for "C++", I get an error on this line.

```
needles = "C++ Developer"
regal = re.compile(r"(%s)" % "|".join(needles), re.I)
# error: multiple repeat
```

How to avoid the above error without manipulating the needles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape all the metacharacters in your plain text.

**EDIT:**

```
>>> re.escape("C++ Developer")
'C\\+\\+\\ Developer'
>>> re.escape(r'\+*.][')
'\\\\\\+\\*\\.\\]\\['
```

Comment: Mind elaborating just a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

You must manipulate the "needles" variable as you have written it if you want to search for plus signs.  Just escape your plus signs:

`needles = "C\\+\\+ Developer"`

Comment: ... And any other regex specials. `re.escape(string)` does this for you.